# Can I rename Main.mxml?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, naming-conventions, mxml

We have several Flash objects included in our project.  We call each one a specific type of widget... For readability/debugging purposes I'd like to rename Main.mxml to something else.

At first this seemed easy, as it would be just a setting in our maven configuration (we're using flex mojos to build our swf).

However; changing the sourceFile from Main.mxml to MyWidget.mxml doesn't seem to do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you change the name name of main.mxml you need to also change the embed code to load the new SWf name

Comment: In Flash Builder it is easy to change the name of the main application file.  If you're compiling using Maven, you'll have to do something to tell Maven what the new name of the main application file is.  I don't much about Maven, so can't offer more specifics.  You specify the main application using the command line compiler using double '- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7fe9.html

Comment: Yeah I just found some other problems with the build process that was causing the behavior I saw.  I was able to change the name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change the name, just be sure the HTML wrapper references the correct name.

We are using Flex Mojos and to change the name we just needed to update the *sourceFile* parameter.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the correct answer to your question. :-)